# Help with light fixture replacement; no ground wire

Tags: light-fixture

Replacing and old light fixture in the laundry room, and this what I see when I remove the cover. Old light fixture is still attached in the photo. I don't see a ground wire in the electrical box, but there are four wire nuts, two of which I don't know what they're connecting.

[image]

The new light fixture (flush), like almost all new light fixtures nowadays, have a ground wire along with the hot and neutral. The old light fixture doesn't have a ground wire.

I don't really know how to proceed since I don't see a ground wire in the electrical box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see a ground bundle behind the wire nutted connections with a metal crimp. For many areas the crimp was required in the past.
Move the wires out 1 wire may be longer allowing you to pigtail a new ground   I have cleaned the texture and paint off the ground in the past and crimped a pigtail on because the crimp is usually two close to the end to use a wire nut. But your grounds do look to be there. A metal fixture should have the ground connected a plastic one it doesn’t need the ground.

Comment: +1 there's a twisted ground in the very back... pisses me off when I see they shot texture paint in there... arrg

Comment: You just might be right, I think I see it now too.+

Answer (score 2):

Good for you for not taking all the wires apart and then asking how to put them all back together.

Turn the power off at the breaker and then remove the two wire nuts that go directly to your old light. Don't touch the two tucked away in the junction box. Connect the black wire from the box to the black wire from your fixture using one of the yellow wire nuts. Do the same with the white wire from the box to the white wire from your fixture.

Ed sees a bundle of ground wires in the back covered with paint. You'll need to attach your ground wire to them. Cut the crimp off, clean them off and connect your ground wire to them with a wire nut.
Mount your new fixture to the junction box following any instructions they included in the packaging.